# goto main fragment on click of a button in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, program-entry-point

I am sending an email on click of a button and after successful attempt Main activity has to open

```
((MainActivity) mContext).startActivityForResult(main,
                        FragmentCartPreview.MAIL_REQUEST_CODE);
```

I tried the above code, but the application closes.

Comment: Are you on fragment??? when calling the above code??

Comment: Thanks for the help...Figured it out

Answer (score 0):

Assuming...you are making this call from a frgament, you can override onActivityResult() in your fragment... when you get the desired result...(say RESULT_OK)...you can make a fragment transaction to any desired fragment.